# Calling C function in Fortran with variable length array arguments

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to pass a 1D array from Fortran to C and get an output array back to Fortran through a routine. The function is simple and for demonstration purpose. It takes in a 2 variable length arrays, one of which is empty, and stores the second value in the corresponding location for the empty one. The source code is as follows

**binder.f90**

```
module binder
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  interface
    subroutine eval_jacob(t,p,y,jac) bind(c)
      use iso_c_binding
      real(c_double) :: t
      real(c_double) :: p
      real(c_double) :: y(*)
      real(c_double), intent(out) :: jac(*)
      end subroutine eval_jacob
  end interface

end module
```

I've included a `printf` in the function just for verification purposes.

**func.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void eval_jacob(double t,double p,double* y,double* jac) {
  jac[1] = y[1];
  printf("%f",jac[1]);

  return;
}
```

The test program initializes `y` with the same value of `0.1`. However, the output from both statements is `0`.

**test.f90**

```
program test_f
  use binder
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  real(c_double) :: t = 0.d0
  real(c_double) :: p = 101325.d0
  integer, parameter :: NN = 11

  real(c_double) :: y(NN)
  real(c_double) :: jac(NN)

  integer :: i


  do i = 1,NN
    y(i) = 1.0d-1
  end do

  call eval_jacob(t,p,y,jac)
  write(*,*), jac(2)

end program
```

Comment: What if you add the `value` attribute to the dummies `t` and `p` in the interface block?

Comment: If you use iso_c_binding, don't use `kind=8` it is really very ugly. And if you must use this ugly and non-portable way, be careful that `101325.0` and `0.1` are single precision numbers. And with `0.1` it does matter.

Comment: Even if you were to use standard data kinds of different names, e.g. real64 and c_double,  you aren't guaranteed that a compiler will recognize correctly the same or differing kinds.

Comment: I'd suggest to try @francescalus approach as by default Fortran passes arguments by reference. Moreover, since you have arrays and in C they are represented as pointers you need to pass a variable of type `c_ptr` to the function which you can obtain using `c_loc`.

Comment: The addition of value attribute solved the issue. There was no requirement to use c_ptr as @Chaosit mentioned. I've also updated the precision to use `c_double` and defined the floating point numbers using `.d` as appopriately, based on @Vladimir F's comment.